# How to access textBox placed on sheet in VBA module?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have placed a TextBox control on a sheet in Excel, in a VBA module I want to acces the TextBox and populate with content.

How do I reference the TextBox control?

I've named the TextBox 'tbSQL', in the module I can see Application and can refernece the sheet from the module, the sheet is called 'Database Info.'

I want to write data into the TextBox from the VBA module, but so far I haven't been able to reference it.

I've tried:

```
    Public Const DATABASE_INFO As String = "Database Info."

    Dim objDBsheet As Worksheet, objSQL As Range
    Dim tbSQL As TextBox
    Set objDBsheet = Application.Sheets(DATABASE_INFO)
    Set tbSQL = objDBsheet.Shapes("tbSQL")
```

But this is as far as I get it errors on the Set tbSQL line.  The reported error is "Type Mismatch"

I know the control is a TextBox, it was created from the Controlbox toolbar.  When looking in the range bar in Excel it displays:

```
    "=EMBED("Forms.TextBox.1","")"
```

In the Properties box for the TextBox control I have set the (Name) property to tbSQL, however it remains unchanged in the fx text box.  It does show as tbSQL in the range box.

Comment: Is it a form control or an ActiveX control?

Comment: I've just used the stock TextBox from the ControlToolbox.

Comment: It will be either form or ActiveX. Did you use the "Insert" button on the "Developer" tab?

Comment: I should have said this is Excel 2003 SP3.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. See below. That should do it. Please post back if not.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @David, Type mismatch

Comment: You'll need to identify what type of object it is. It's not a `TextBox` type. It's probably a `Shape`.

Comment: @David, I am 100% positive it is a TextBox.

Comment: See my answer for how to handle SHapes, Form Controls, or ActiveX controls

Comment: It doesn't hellp, sorry.

Comment: I'd have to find my old laptop with Excel 2003 on it... that may take a while.

Comment: BTW you're aware that Office 2003 has been unsupported by Microsoft for several years now...

Comment: Yep, i have it though and don't want to upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117356/discussion-between-david-zemens-and-splatten).

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like it is a bug in Excel 2003, I was able to reference the control by using Sheet1.tbSQL instead of going through Application.Sheets.

Comment: hmmm not that it should (usually) matter, but I wonder if `Application.Worksheets` or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` would have worked?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely its a bug in Excel. It has nothing to do with Excel-2003.

If you use a `Worksheet` type variable then Excel fails to discover the control on that sheet in VBA. So if you declare your sheet holding variable  as Object / Variant , the code will work fine.

Other alternative is to directly use the Worksheet's `CodeName`, so if you set the Worksheet's name as `wksDBSheet` in the VBA IDE's property grid and use that in your code, it will discover the `TextBox`

```
Sub test()
    Dim objDBsheet As Object 'As Worksheet  // Making the 0bjDBSheet type as Object or Variant
                                           '// Allows the discovery of the TextBox on the sheet.
                                           '// Most Likely its a bug.
    Dim objSQL As Range

    Dim tbSQL As MSForms.TextBox
    Set objDBsheet = Application.Worksheets("Database Info.")
    Set tbSQL = objDBsheet.tbSQL
    tbSQL.Text = "Bug"


    '/  Other Alternative is to directly use the CddeName of the sheet.
    Set tbSQL = wksDBsheet.tbSQL
    tbSQL.Text = "Code Name used"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is only for ActiveX. If it is a form control, this will not work.

Comment: Tried this before I posted on StackOverflow, the control is not accessible from the sheet.

Comment: Would this also work? `objDBsheet.OLEObjects("tbSql")`? (even declaring `objDBSheet as Worksheet`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Shapes("tbSQL").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Anything you want"
```

Comment: is there a Text property for Shapes?

Comment: @cyboashu no, you'd need `.TextFrame.Characters.Text`

Comment: @DavidZemens yup. I sued the same in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Text Box as shape, or Label as Form Control, or ActiveX control:

```
Sub f()
Dim tb As Shape, lblControl As Object, lblActiveX As Object
Set tb = Sheet1.Shapes("TextBox 1")
Set lblControl = Sheet1.Shapes("Label 2").OLEFormat.Object
Set lblActiveX = Sheet1.Shapes("Label1").OLEFormat.Object

lblControl.Text = "Form Control"
lblActiveX.Object.Caption = "ActiveX Control"
tb.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Text Box"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put an ActiveX texbox on a worksheet named "MyTextBox" then you can [set it's text](https://www.engram9.info/excel-vba-macros/referring-to-a-control-on-a-worksheet.html) in vba like this:

```
ActiveSheet.MyTextBox.Text = "hi"
```